# unit testing django ModelFormset clean methods

Tags: python, django, forms, unit-testing

What is the best way to unit test the validation/clean part of a Django ModelFormset? My formset has a clean method that does some validation based on the values of its forms and I want to have a unit test for it. Generified code look like this:

```
class AForm(ModelForm):
    a = ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
    b = FloatField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(AForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
       model = AModel
       fields =['a', 'b']


class AFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def clean(self):
       # Some logic to validate relationships between the forms
```

But while testing the form is trivial: `form = AForm(formdata)` and then verifying its validity or errors based on the data. I'm having trouble writing tests for the formset.

I've tried:

```
    formset = AFormset()
```

And using `modelformset_factory`

```
Formset = modelformset_factory(AModel, AForm, formset=AFormset, fields=('a', 'b'))
formset = Formset(formdata)
```

with various combinations of arguments and mocks (instance, queryset). But I always get errors related to model foreign or primary keys. One example:

```
Error Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/tests/test_forms.py", line 62, in test_validation formset = Formset(formdata)
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 853, in __init__
self.instance = self.fk.rel.to()
AttributeError: 'AFormset' object has no attribute 'fk'
```

What am I missing? Is there an easier way to instantiate a formset with a dictionary of data and have it run its `clean` method? Should I just test the view that the form is used in? (In the views I'm using the form and formset with the [Django Extra Views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views) package)

Comment: Where *exactly* are you getting that error? Please show the full code of the test.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I updated the question to include the traceback. I get different errors based on how I'm testing it, but they all relate to db functionality of the related model. Is it not possible to test the formset without setting up mocks for all the related models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with your test, but has to do with an incompatibility between your base formset class and the formset factory.

Your AFormset class inherits from BaseInlineFormSet. That class expects an `fk` property to exist, which should determine the foreign key of the form model to the object to which it is "inline". That property is created by the `inlineformset_factory` function. However, you are using `modelformset_factory` to construct your concrete formset class; this does not set that `fk` property.

You should either use `inlineformset_factory` (and pass in the parent model), or change your formset class to inherit from BaseModelFormSet if it is not actually inline.